# Problems sending several different Android Intents to open app

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm facing a problem sending different intents via URIs to the same **open** app.

In my Manifest file, I've got the following entries :

```
<intent-filter>
<data
android:scheme="http"
android:host="my-domain.com"
/>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

I want my app to start if it is not opened yet and to resume if it is.
From an email link, I want to start ths app via URL :

```
http://my-domain.com/activate?code=abcdef
```

In my app, I receive the intent in onRestart, analyze it and consume it. It works.
But when I call another mail with another code, e.g.

```
http://my-domain.com/activate?code=ghijkl
```

and the app is still open, I'm not able to pick the data from second call. Every time I try I'll get the data from first call. I'm not able to drop the Intent after consuming.

What can I do to accomplish to read the data from second call keeping the app alive ?
It works if the app is not opened yet but that's not enough... I haven't found any answer concerning this problem and solving it... Is there anybody here with an applicable solution ?

thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: I think the onResume() is called when you open the app again reason being it has not been fully stopped leaving the same state

Comment: No, the app has not fully stopped when I send the second URL.... But that's the desired state of the app. How can I force that the ap will consume the content of the second URL  and not of the first ?

Comment: Clearing intent doesn't help since it doesn't remove the intent and the app gets its data from this "empty" intent, not from the other